# Is it possible to change value of a defined constant?

Tags: php, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the value of a previously-defined constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481869/change-the-value-of-a-previously-defined-constant)

There is a constant ABC and I need to get its value, save it, change, do some actions and restore. But I was told that it isn't possible. Please, tell me, is it true? If no, tell me, how can I get value from a constant and set my value for it?

Comment: Yes, it's true, a constant as the name tells it can't be changed.

Comment: `$copyconstant = CONSTANT;` Should be about it to get it in a variable to work with.

Comment: Same as how you assign variable to variable, `define("ABC", "foo"); $bar = ABC;`

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. The point of a constant is to not be changed, and once a constant is defined it cannot be redefined or deleted.

However there are options. You could use normal variables or maybe this can be helpfull in some way: [Un-define constants with define/apc_define_constants in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217074/un-define-constants-with-define-apc-define-constants-in-php)

According to that post you can use the apc_* functions to undefine and define it. So you can change it in the fashion of deleting it, and creating it again with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the CONSTANT in other var and use it as global..refer below e.g.

```
$copyconstant = CONSTANT_VAR;

Then use $copyconstant declaring as global in pages;

global $copyconstant; 
echo $copyconstant;
```

Answer (score 0):

Constants are meant to be constant and do not change, what you are asking to do requires the use of a variable.